# MVC 5 setting focus to hyperlink in IE doesn't click with Enter button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-11

I have a Bootstrap modal that is like an Alert with just an "OK" button in it. I've got the code to where it will set focus to the "OK" button when the modal is displayed but when I press Enter the link doesn't click. It does in Chrome but not in IE.

This is what is rendered to the page and when the page shows I see the dotted line around the button showing it has focus.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="linkOK" href="/LogOut">OK</a>
```

Anyone know why the click won't fire in Internet Explorer 11 when a hyperlink has focus?

Comment: works on my machine. minimum example plz?

Comment: If I click on the button it works. It just doesn't seem to work with the Enter button when I set focus using jQuery. It only seems to be IE 11 as well, Chrome works as expected.

Comment: what happen when you set the focus using tab key

Comment: Finally figured out a fix. I still couldn't get it to fire off a click event even when using jQuery but I was able to look at the KeyPress and see if it was the Enter button. Then I checked to see if the Bootstrap Modal was showing and if so then I had to use a window.location and route to the link I wanted. The linkId.click() event would never fire in IE. Chrome worked just fine.